# Randomization/ permutation test

Tags: r

I have a panel data that looks like this:

```
x <- structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11), private = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), capex = c(-0.003423963, -0.028064674, -0.03058208, 
-0.00186256, -0.010839419, 0.052905358, 0.058931317, 0.065547734, 
0.007644231, -0.025942514, 0.00163772, -0.007530502, 0.010706151, 
0.025040116, 0.035105374, 0.036772128, 0.03886272, 0.045399148, 
0.042642809, 0.080788992, 0.080848917, 0.057645567, 0.057636742, 
0.046084184, 0.041080192, 0.05690382, 0.057325598, 0.051791377, 
0.070084445, 0.069627948, 0.077849329, 0.077247024, 0.081251919, 
0.071702167, 0.078424804, 0.077482991, 0.078969546, 0.076208547, 
0.059055354, 0.056043826, 0.029450929, 0.016044363, 0.048353843, 
0.047607671, 0.046497576, 0.047454875, 0.050881654, 0.047155183, 
0.055546004, 0.057564467), roa = c(-0.003078416, -0.035302367, 
-0.01884984, 0.002839225, -0.001113289, 0.024291474, 0.040153231, 
0.051482957, 0.026102768, 0.005372915, 0.004466314, -0.025178509, 
-0.002043936, -0.069235161, 0.023604594, 0.010512878, 0.021912357, 
0.016721437, -0.09472625, 0.04061316, 0.074661337, 0.0214584, 
0.047743626, 0.013149141, -0.010418181, 0.025671346, 0.031785361, 
0.084893651, 0.018490626, 0.024941774, 0.023567598, 0.031878859, 
0.029931206, 0.043837443, 0.041305128, 0.041293647, 0.039307728, 
0.046259467, 0.017479861, 0.029429797, 0.023826957, 0.00763736, 
0.017485917, 0.017156925, 0.006504506, 0.021350464, 0.032917287, 
0.036106978, 0.04545372, 0.049348988), year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2011, 2012, 2013)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Where `id2` is firm ID and `private` is an indicator for private/public status. My goal is to run a randomization test for r-squared as follows:

- regress `roa` on `capex` for private firms (i.e. private==1) and public (private==0) separately and get the observed difference in R-squared
- randomly assign firms to private-public status (note that the data is panel)
- rerun the regression and get the difference in r-squared for the random sample
- repeat this, say, 1000 times
- measure the p-value as the number of times that the randomly generated difference in R2 is larger than the observed difference divided by the number of iterations (1,000)

My issue is that this code takes ages to run, it will be great if someone has an idea of a better way to do this.

*you will need `estimatr` and `tidyverse` packages to run this code*

```
library(estimatr)
library(tidyverse)

# run model 1
mod1 <-lm_robust(roa ~ capex,
                 cluster=id2,
                 se_type = "stata",
                 data=x,private==0)
# run model 2
mod2 <-lm_robust(roa ~ capex,
                 cluster=id2,
                 se_type = "stata",
                 data=x,private==1)

#obtain the observed difference in R2
R2.obs1 <- summary(mod1)$adj.r.squared
R2.obs2 <- summary(mod2)$adj.r.squared
diff_r2_obs <- R2.obs2 - R2.obs1
]

#create a list for the simulated differnce in r2
simulated_r2 <- list()

# prepare the loop 

set.seed(8)
nreps = 1000 

for(i in 1:nreps){
  x1 <- x %>%      # randamize the variable private taking into acount each id appears a number of times 
    distinct(id2, private) %>% 
    mutate(private1=sample(private), replace=T) %>% 
    left_join(x, by="id2")  
  
  model_m <-lm_robust(roa ~ capex,
                      cluster=id2,
                      se_type = "stata",
                      data = x1,
                      subset=private1==0)
  R2.obs_m <- summary(model_m)$adj.r.squared
  
  model_f <-lm_robust(roa ~ capex,
                      cluster=id2,
                      se_type = "stata",
                      data = x1,
                      subset=private1==1)
  
  R2.obs_f <- summary(model_f)$adj.r.squared
  r2_diff_sim <- R2.obs_f - R2.obs_m
  simulated_r2[i] <- r2_diff_sim
  
}

simulated_r2 <- unlist(simulated_r2)

exceed_count <- length(simulated_r2[simulated_r2 >=
                                          diff_r2_obs])
p_val <- exceed_count / nreps

p_val
```

Comment: two quick questions: 1) how long (nrows) is your actual dataset (and how many unique groups - how many unique id2s); 2) are you sure you want replace=T when you permute the private status

Comment: @langtang Maybe `replace=FALSE` (the default) solves the problem of occurring warnings (see my answer), the private statuses would be identical distributed in each iteration, not sure what OP needs.

Comment: I have got about 3,000 observations and 300 unique ids. I will need to report both `replace=T` and `replace=F`

Answer (score 1):

I initialized `simulated_r2` as a vector rather than a list. We benefit a lot when we predefine it's `length=`.  Also I replaced the `dplyr` code with an `transform` approach which appears to be faster. Runs quite fast with 1000 reps on this data actually. (Note, that in your code there was a mistake when using `sample`, the `replace=` argument is outside the call but should be inside!)

```
nreps <- 1000
simulated_r2 <- numeric(length=nreps)

set.seed(8)
system.time(
  for (i in seq_len(nreps)) {
    x1 <- transform(subset(x, !duplicated(id2)), 
                    private=sample(private, replace=T))
    model_m <- estimatr::lm_robust(roa ~ capex, clusters=id2, se_type="stata",
                                   data=x1, subset=private == 0)
    R2.obs_m <- summary(model_m)$adj.r.squared
    model_f <- estimatr::lm_robust(roa ~ capex, clusters=id2, se_type="stata", 
                                   data=x1, subset=private == 1)
    R2.obs_f <- summary(model_f)$adj.r.squared
    r2_diff_sim <- R2.obs_f - R2.obs_m
    simulated_r2[i] <- r2_diff_sim
  } 
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 8.262   0.000   8.267 

(p_val <- length(simulated_r2[simulated_r2 >= diff_r2_obs])/nreps)
# [1] 0.273
```

Note, that warnings occur if you set `replace=TRUE`, probably when the nobs of one of the subsets on 0/1 get to small. You should rethink your approach a little.

#### Parallelize

If this is too slow, you could parallelize the code.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, 'x')
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 8)  ## set seed

nreps <- 10000
system.time(
  simulated_r2 <- parSapplyLB(cl, seq_len(nreps), \(i) {
    x1 <- transform(subset(x, !duplicated(id2)), 
                    private=sample(private, replace=F))
    model_m <- estimatr::lm_robust(roa ~ capex, clusters=id2, se_type="stata",
                                   data=x1, subset=private == 0)
    R2.obs_m <- summary(model_m)$adj.r.squared
    model_f <- estimatr::lm_robust(roa ~ capex, clusters=id2, se_type="stata", 
                                   data=x1, subset=private == 1)
    R2.obs_f <- summary(model_f)$adj.r.squared
    R2.obs_f - R2.obs_m
  })
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.067   0.058  17.820 

(p_val <- length(simulated_r2[simulated_r2 >= diff_r2_obs])/nreps)
# [1] 0.257

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I have an issue with `FUN=\(x)`  - i get: `Error: unexpected input in:
"  for (i in seq_len(nreps)) {
    x1 <- transform(x, private=ave(private, id2, FUN=\"`

Comment: @Tim Update your R or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Comment: @Tim I rewrote the `transform` a little, now both `replace=FALSE` and `replace=TRUE` is possible.

Comment: thanks a lot @jay.sf !! this is great!

Comment: @Tim Glad to hear that!

Comment: @Tim BTW, Please consider to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on Stack Overflow if it helped you to signalize others that the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This takes a different approach to jay.sf's nice solution.  Here, I use data.table, create the random permutations of private/public status, use a small function to get difference(s) in r-sq:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

set.seed(8)

nperms=1000

# get permutations of public/private status
perms = cbind(unique(x[,.(id2)]), unique(x[,.(id2,private)])[,lapply(1:nperms, function(p) sample(private, replace=F))])

# function to get R-sq differences
obsR <- function(r,c,id,p) {
  r0 = lm_robust(r[p==0]~c[p==0],clusters=id[p==0],se_type="stata")$adj.r.squared
  r1 = lm_robust(r[p==1]~c[p==1],clusters=id[p==1],se_type="stata")$adj.r.squared
  r1-r0
}

# empirical r-sq diff
empirR = x[, obsR(roa,capex,id2,private)]

# simulated r-sq differences
simR = x[perms, on=.(id2)][, sapply(.SD, function(v) obsR(roa,capex,id2,v)), .SDcols = patterns("V")]

# pvalue
sum(simR>=empirR)/nperms
```

With the small provided dataset, this can do a thousand estimates and get the p-value in under 5 seconds on my machine.

```
   user  system elapsed 
   4.56    0.14    4.70
```

Comment: Nice, gives a different _p_ value though, do you know why?

Comment: good catch @jay.sf.  I'm not positive, but I think the OP made a mistake with the original empirical r-sq difference.  There is no subset call in the original code.. Should be `subset=private==0` and `subset=private==1`.

Comment: Anyway it's noted now. Your code runs >10% faster than mine, I'm sure it would make the 10k reps in < 10secs if parallelized.

Comment: @langtang: this is fantastic! thank you.